# Python 3.5 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I have been trying to use `tensorflow` to build a simple neural network using PyCharm. I have managed to install the `tensorflow` package(see image below) but the following error appears when I try to run the application.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/abc/Desktop/new-app/neuraln.py", line 1, in
>   
>       import tensorflow as tf ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

[image]

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

*Note - I'm not using `conda` env*

Comment: Can you provide more details of how you installed tensorflow? Also it looks like your environment needs updating (fairly old versions of everything). Could pycharm not know about your conda setup?

Comment: I installed tensorflow using the `pip install tensorflow` command and I'm **not** using the conda environment because I'm having an issue with using `Flask-MySQLdb` with it.

Comment: Pycharm might be using a different python version than the one you installed tensorflow in. Can you check where tf is installed and what your pythonpath is?